# Prestashop : use custom hooks in default modules without modifying their PHP files

Tags: php, module, overriding, hook, prestashop

I'm working on a project based on the latest beta of Prestashop (1.5 RC) since I need some stuff that's new in this version.

Before going to production, the website will of course be updated to the stable 1.5 version when it comes out, and it's planned to be kept up-to-date with the following stable releases.

As the design is kind of specific, I had to create custom hooks to place modules on. What's bothering me is that my modules (and especially the "default" ones, that come with Prestashop) logically don't have the required method that allows them to be places on the hooks I created.

I added these methods to their PHP files, but when Prestashop (or any concerned module) will get updated, my changes will be discarded and I'll have to write it all over again.

Is there any way to make these modules able to be placed on whatever hook I want without directly modifying their own code ? AFAIK you can't override a module's PHP file, you can do it with TPL, CSS and JS only.

Any help greatly appreciated. My searches on related topics on Prestashop's own forum lead mer to think you simply can't do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around the problem with adding hooks by using smarty plugins to call the module hook functions at an arbitrary location in the theme. I wrote an article in my blog that may help calling them [Prestashop Plugins](http://www.ecartservice.net/prestashop-articles/1-4-plugins-revisited-part-1/). Obviously the code could be expanded to include things like passing additional parameters etc. Once implemented though you can do things like this in your tpl files:

To display (i.e. call) the "Home Featured" module's hookHome function

```
{plugin module='homefeatured' hook='home'}
```

To display the value of a settings variable (handy to save changing hard-coded values everywhere!)

```
{psconfig item='PS_SHOP_PHONE'}
```

And finally (as far as the examples go) to display the contents of a CMS page:

```
{cmspage id='1'}
```

The possibilities are endless for the creative store developer ;)

Comment: Very nice, thank you ! I still think the lack of this in "core" Prestashop is quite a big deal. Hopefully I'll be able to work things out with your solution. Your blog post just joined my bookmarks !